# Spring boot create many entity manager

Tags: spring, spring-boot, entitymanager

In a spring boot application, when i start it, i see 68 times this line:

```
tor$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler [main] - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
```

I have 8 jpa entity.

any reason to have so many entity manager created?

Edit

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=false

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/cnn
spring.datasource.username=cnn
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

Comment: can you add the spring configuration of your  project?

Comment: don't have any config class.... only application properties